# How do I set a default document in IIS?

Tags: iis

I want to set index.html to be served as my default document. This is on Windows Server 2012r2.

All the tutorials say to double-click the 'Default document' option, but I don't have that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see default document, you need to install that feature through the Add Roles and Features Wizard:

[image]